# How shall I understand the undesirable consequences of dynamic scoping?

Tags: programming-languages

In *Practical Foundation of Programming Languages* by Harper

> **8.4 Dynamic Scope**
>
> Another approach, called dynamic scoping, or dynamic binding, is sometimes advocated
>   as an alternative to static binding. The crucial difference is that **with dynamic scoping the
>   principle of identiﬁcation of abt’s up to renaming of bound variables is denied. Consequently, capture-avoiding substitution is not available.** Instead, evaluation is deﬁned for
>   open terms, with the bindings of free variables provided by an environment mapping variable names to (possibly open) values. The binding of a variable is determined as late as
>   possible, at the point where the variable is evaluated, rather than where it is bound. If the
>   environment does not provide a binding for a variable, evaluation is aborted with a run-time
>   error.
>
> In the higher-order case, the equivalence of static and dynamic scope
>   breaks down. For example, consider the expression
>
> ```
>  e = (λ (x : num) λ (y : num) x + y)(42).
> ```
>
> With static scoping `e` evaluates to the closed value `v = λ (y : num) 42 + y`, which, if applied, would add `42` to its argument. It makes
>   no difference how the bound variable `x` is chosen, the outcome will
>   always be the same. With dynamic scoping, `e` evaluates to the open
>   value `v'  = λ (y : num) x + y` in which the variable `x` occurs free.
>   When this expression is evaluated, the variable `x` is bound to `42`,
>   but this is irrelevant because the binding is not needed to evaluate
>   the λ-abstraction. The binding of `x` is not retrieved until such time
>   as `v'` is applied to an argument, at which point the binding for `x`
>   in force at that time is retrieved,and not the one in force at the
>   point where `e` is evaluated.
>
> Therein lies the difference. For example, consider the expression
>
> ```
> e' = (λ (f : num → num) (λ (x : num) f (0))(7))(e)`.
> ```
>
> When evaluated using dynamic scope, the value of `e'` is `7`, whereas
>   its value is `42` under static scope. The discrepancy can be traced to
>   the rebinding of `x` to `7` before the value of `e`, namely `v'`, is
>   applied to `0`, altering the outcome.
>
> Dynamic scope violates the basic principle that variables are given
>   meaning by capture-avoiding substitution as deﬁned in Chapter 1.
>   Violating this principle has at least two undesirable consequences.
>
> One is that the names of bound variables matter, in contrast to static
>   scope which obeys the identiﬁcation principle. For example, **had the
>   innermost λ-abstraction of `e'` bound the variable `y`, rather than
>   `x`, then its value would have been `42`, rather than `7`**. Thus, one
>   component of a program may be sensitive to the names of bound
>   variables chosen in another component, a clear violation of modular
>   decomposition.
>
> Another problem is that dynamic scope is not, in general, type-safe.
>   For example, consider the expression
>
> ```
> e' = (λ (f : num → num) (λ (x : str) f ("zero"))(7))(e)
> ```
>
> **Under dynamic scoping this expression gets stuck attempting to
>   evaluate `x + y` with `x` bound to the string `“zero”`**, and no further
>   progress can be made.

What does it mean by "with dynamic scoping the
principle of identiﬁcation of abt’s up to renaming of bound variables is denied" and "consequently, capture-avoiding substitution is not available"?

Why under dynamic scoping, "had the innermost λ-abstraction of `e'` bound the variable `y`, rather than  `x`, then its value would have been `42`, rather than `7`"? How does  "static scope  obey the identiﬁcation principle" here?

How "Under dynamic scoping this expression gets stuck attempting to evaluate `x + y` with `x` bound to the string `“zero”`"?  Isn't it that `x` in `e'` is bound to `7`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're right that that example is a bit confused. I believe the fix is the following, if I got my parantheses right.

```
e' = (λ (f : num → num) (λ (x : str) f ("zero"))(7))(e)
```

should instead be

```
e' = (λ (f : num → num) (λ (x : str) f) ("zero"))(e)(7)
```

If we evaluate e first we'll get:

```
(λ (x : num) λ (y : num) x + y)(42).

x = 42
(λ (y : num) x + y).
```

We've finished evaluating e, since we got to a lambda. But evaluating it in the above expression will cause the bad addition "zero" + 42, since, regardless of what we do with the environment, the x="zero" binding will be the closest. The immediate reduction of the above gives:

Comment: Something seems missing from the end of your answer.  Did it get truncated?